# Grabbing the current tab name

Tags: vim

I am using taboo.vim to rename tabs.  Is there some way in gvim and vim to evaluate whether the current tab title is equal to something? i.e.

```
if tabname == 'config'
    " do something
endif
```

Is there any way to grab the tab name for use like this?

```
iabbr tabname givecurrenttabname
```

Typing `tabname` would result in `config` if that was the name of the current tab.

I'm trying to setup up specific mappings based on what I name a tab for use with unite bookmarks. Specifically I would like to be able to use a single mapping that will open up a bookmark file of the same name as the tab. e.g.

```
nnoremap <space>u :Unite bookmark:'tabname'
```

My current way of doing this is by checking the buffer name, but since I have a lot of configuration files I would open in a tab called config, this just seems very inefficient:

```
if bufname("%") == "bufname1"
    nnoremap <buffer> <space>u :Unite bookmark:config
elseif bufname("%") == "bufname2"
    nnoremap <buffer> <space>u :Unite bookmark:config
...
elseif bufname("%") == "bufname40"
    nnoremap <buffer> <space>u :Unite bookmark:text
endif
```

If I could use something like tabname, then I wouldn't have to add new files to this all the time.

Edit: For anyone who wants to use unite and taboo to have a single mapping to open a bookmark file with the same name as the tab, thanks to Ingo Karkat I have now put the following in my .vimrc :

```
cnoreabbr <expr> tabname t:taboo_tab_name
nnoremap <buffer> <space>u :Unite -quick-match bookmark:tabname<C-]><cr>
```

Comment: You are using tabpages the wrong way. Stick with buffers.

Comment: @romainl There is no right way to use tab pages, and I am using them as viewports as is usually suggested, so how am I using them wrong? My use of tabs increases efficiency. It allows me to access my most used files in two keystrokes and 50+ (potentially much more and still without finger movement away from the home row) commonly accessed files in 2,3, or 5 keystrokes maximum (2 requires memorization; 3 does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the *taboo.vim* plugin, but it looks like it stores the tab name in a tab-local `t:taboo_tab_name` variable.

To generate tab page-specific mappings and abbreviations, you can use `:help :map-expr`, e.g.:

```
:iabbr <expr> tabname "this is " . t:taboo_tab_name
```